# Python Removing Columns

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to remove the last two columns from my data frame by using Python.

The issue is there are cells with values in the last two columns that we don't need, and those columns don't have headers.

Here's the code I wrote, but I'm really new to Python, and don't know how to take my original data and remove the last two columns.

```
import csv
with open("Filename","rb") as source:
    rdr= csv.reader( source )
    with open("Filename","wb") as result:
        wrt= csv.writer ( result )
        for r in rdr:
            wrt.writerow( (r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4], r[5], r[6], r[7], r[8], r[9], r[10], r[11]) )
```

Thanks!

Comment: remove the last two from `writerow` ... `r[10],r[11]` ...

Comment: replace your last line with `wrt.writerow(r[:-2])`

Comment: I just tried this approach:     wrt.writerow(rdr[:-2]) and my file was overwritten  with nothing? The file was essentially erased?

Comment: well yeah... you should use `wrt.writerow(r[:-2])` , note the **r** not **rdr**

Comment: I changed the last row to this:  wrt.writerow(r[:-2] and the file is still being overwritten with nothing @Joran Beasley

Comment: well if the file you are opening is empty the file you are writing to will be as well ...

Comment: Ok, going back to my original approach, selecting the first 12 columns as (r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4], r[5], r[6], r[7], r[8], r[9], r[10], r[11]), I am getting the error "IndexError: list index out of range" I have 12 columns when I open it in sublime text

Answer (score 3):

The proper Pythonic way to perform something like this is through *slicing*:

```
r[start:stop(:step)]
```

`start` and `stop` are indexes, where positive indexes are counted from the front and negative is counted from the end. Blank `start`s and `stop`s are treated as the beginning and the end of `r` respectively.  `step` is an optional parameter that I'll explain later.  Any slice returns an array, which you can perform additional operations on or just return immediately.

In order to remove the last two values, you can use the slice

```
r[:-2]
```

#### Additional fun with `step`

Now that `step` parameter.  It allows you to pick every `step`th value from the selected slice.  With an array of, say, `r = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` you can pick every other number starting with the first (all of the even numbers) with the slice `r[::2]`.  In order to get results in reverse order, you can make the step negative:

```
> r = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
> r[::-1]
[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
```